# Powershell - Set-AzureADApplication Application Permission for Public Client

Tags: azure-ad-powershell-v2

**Issue Description:**

during trying to use the following command to create Daemon application for PublicClient, it failed.  if confgired PublicClient as False, it works.

**Issue Repro:**

```
Connect-AzureAD
$svcprincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

#Microsoft Graph
$reqGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = $svcprincipal.AppId

##Delegated Permissions
$delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "0e263e50-5827-48a4-b97c-d940288653c7","Scope" #Access Directory as the signed in user

##Application Permissions
$appPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "62a82d76-70ea-41e2-9197-370581804d09","Role" #Read and Write All Groups
$appPermission2 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "19dbc75e-c2e2-444c-a770-ec69d8559fc7","Role" #Read and Write directory data

# when Set PublicClient as False, it worked.
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName pca-test3 -ReplyUrls https://localhost/ -AvailableToOtherTenants $true -PublicClient $false -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph

# when Set PublicClient as True, it failed
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName pca-test3 -ReplyUrls https://localhost/ -AvailableToOtherTenants $true -PublicClient $true -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph`
```

**ErrorMessage:**

Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Property requiredResourceAccess.resourceAccess is invalid.
Details: PropertyName  - requiredResourceAccess.resourceAccess, PropertyErrorCode  - GenericError
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed

anyone can provide some suggestions or helps? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create Azure AD application as public client, we cannot configure application permissions for the application. Because these applications are not trusted to safely keep application secrets, so they only access Web APIs on behalf of the user. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications). So we need to configure Delegated permissions for the application. In other words, the permissions' type should be `scope`.

For example

```
Connect-AzureAD

$svcprincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

$reqGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = $svcprincipal.AppId
$delPermission1 = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "0e263e50-5827-48a4-b97c-d940288653c7","Scope" #Sign in and read user profile
$delPermission2 =New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d","Scope" #Access Directory as the signed in user

$reqGraph.ResourceAccess = $delPermission1,$delPermission2

New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName pca-test3 -ReplyUrls https://localhost/ -AvailableToOtherTenants $true -PublicClient $true -RequiredResourceAccess $reqGraph
```

[image]